# Group policy fails to disable Windows Defender on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, group-policy, windows-defender

I have Windows 10 enterprise x64 1903 18362.592 which has been installed for at least 6 months.

I had windows defender disabled via group policy. Since a recent update defender real time scanning gets turned on every time I reboot.

This is my group policy settings:
[image]

[image]
[image]

Note. I still want windows defender installed and doing scheduled scans, I just do not want real time monitoring.

How can I disable real time monitoring and have it persist a reboot?

Comment: No other anti virus products are installed. I haven't set any other GPOs as this was previously working, something has just broken it. What are the latest policy definitions and how do I download those? Thanks

Comment: "Home PC" running enterprise edition.

Comment: I think the latest Policy Definition are included with the Windows Update/version upgrade.I say run from elevated cmd prompt `sfc /scannow` reboot, and then check again. I also suggest running `gpupdate /force /wait:0` and then check the group policy logs from event viewer and look over logs for clues what the issue may be. So in Event Viewer | Microsoft | Group Policy and then look at those logs in that are not just application and system logs, dig deeper in the Event Viewer Apps and Services folder for Group Policy